# Retrieving S3 Object via Java AWS SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using the `getObject`() method of the `AmazonS3Client` class to retrieve an object stored in my S3 bucket.
When calling this method, is the object requested over an SSL connection? Or do I need to encrypt the Object that I am retrieving in case the request is intercepted?

Answer (score 2):

The AWS Java SDK uses SSL by default. You can read more about that here: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1928

Comment: Thanks again. Do you have any insight as to why then someone would do something like client side encryption as outlined here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-s3.html
under "KMS-key"? Isn't this like double encrypting the object that is being sent?

Comment: You are confusing encryption-at-rest with encryption-in-motion. SSL is encryption-in-motion. That link describes encryption-at-rest, which you use to protect your files in the event of an unauthorized person gaining access to your files.